# Is performance testing multiple deployment stacks in one Kuberentes cluster a valid test?

Tags: kubernetes, performance-testing

We have a deployment stack with about 20 microservices/pods. Each deployment goes to its own namespace. To make sure that the cpu and memory are guaranteed for each pod and not shared, we set the request amounts the same as limit amount. Now we sometimes need to deploy more stack into the same performance cluster, e.g. testing different releases of the same stack. The question is whether having more than one deployment in one cluster can invalidate the test result due to shared network or some other reasons?

Initially we were thinking to create one cluster for each performance testing to make sure it is isolated and test results are correct but creating a new cluster and maintaining it a very costly. We also thought about making sure each deployment goes to one node to avoid load testing on one stack impact the others but I'm not sure if that really helps. Please share your knowledge on this as Kubernetes is almost new to us.

Answer (score 0):

If the containers are running on the same underlying hosts then bleedthrough is always possible. If you set all pods into Guaranteed QoS mode (aka requests == limits) then it at least reduces the bleedthrough to a minimum. Running things on one *cluster* is always fine but if you want to truly reduce the crosstalk to zero then you would need dedicated workload nodes for each.